# Is it possible to create a build definition for an ASP.net web site (not an ASP.net application) with TFS Build?

Tags: asp.net, tfs

I have an legacy ASP.net website and would like to create an automated build with TFS Build. I have a lot of troubles with this while doing the same thing with an ASP.net web application works great.

Is there a way to build an ASP.net web site or is it necessary to spend some days to convert the ASP.net web site into an application ?

Regards,

Comment: If your solution is under source control you shouldn't have great problem, add the source working folder, add projects or solution under Process -> build and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. Not really. While you can build and complile there is no helpfull output as a Web Site has no compiled output.

Web Site support is really only still provided for legacy support, and it is best effort support only.

Best option, that I have had to do many times, is to convert your Web Site to an Application.

Its as simple as creating an empty web application and copying the files into the web site folder. Then opening the new project in VS and adding all the files back in. You will need to fix the copy and paste errors that web sites forgive you for, but that has taken my no longer than a few hours even on the largest sites. Bulk update is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, that's exactly what I was expecting :(